# What is the directory architecture of any project in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

By default following directories are created in netbeans:
nbproject
src
build
manifest.mf

Suppose I want to add image and database directory to store images and database. Should these directories be under src? Let me know what is the correct directory architecture of any project in netbeans ?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a too philosophical question under developers. Be more specific for which kind of project.

For web i reccomend something like this:

Src - all your own code

Libraries - all external code

Public - mostly url reachable files and htaccess

Assets - images, media

Styles - the name says it

In your case i would add another folder database

Comment: What is htaccess?
Will media directory under Assets contains video & mp3?
What about JavaScript & JQuery files?

Comment: Yes there where video, mp3, ment. For js it depends on if your app is a js app, then te files goes to src, but when they are assets then they go into assets/js. e.g. in a php app which uses js as decorate.